# Handle exceptions from Mono.zip() depending on type

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to figure out how to handle exceptions that might occur in my code using Spring WebFlux depending on their cause.

I have the following method trying to get information about a product from 2 different external endpoints:

```
public Mono<ProductResponse> getProductInfo(String domain, Long id) {
return Mono.zipDelayError(
        proxy.getDescription(domain, id),
        proxy.getImage(domain, id))
    .map(responses -> ProductResponse.from(responses.getT1(), responses.getT2()));
}
```

If `proxy.getImage` returns a `NOT FOUND` but `proxy.getDescription` returns a successful response, I want to return an object of type `ProductResponse` with the description response only (the image will be null).

But if `proxy.getImage` returns an `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`, I want to return an error, something like `Mono.error(new CustomException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))`.

Right now, what is happening is that if `proxy.getImage` fails, the whole method returns an error. I thought that using `zipDelayError` would return an empty Mono when the request failed, but I think I misunderstood it.

Is it possible to have the behavior I'm describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zipDelayError` completes empty in case any source completes without value. `...DelayError` means that in case several Monos result in error, their exceptions are combined. In contrast `zip` would return error from the first failed `Mono`.

To achieve mentioned logic you would need to handle these errors on the `proxy.getImage` level and in case of `NOT FOUND` return some default value.

```
Mono<Image> getImage(String domain, String id) {
    return proxy.getImage(domain, id)
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                if (NOT FOUND) {
                    // return default value
                    return Mono.just(<default image>)
                } esle if (INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) {
                    // return custom error
                    return Mono.error(new CustomException(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR))
                }

                // return original error
                return Mono.error(e);
            });
}
```